# Twitter API - oauth gem - not getting callback

Tags: oauth, twitter

I redirect the user of my application to Twitter for oauth style authentication using my app's request_token.
The user is able to enter username and password on Twitter's page BUT then, instead of calling back my application, Twitter displays a page

> You've successfully granted access to
>   MyAppName!
>
> Simply return to MyAppName and enter
>   the following PIN to complete the
>   process.
>   123456

Why is this happening?

I have set the callback url in my app's settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Same thing is happening me. I just find the solution.

You can put :oauth_callback parameter to get request token.

Note: Because latest oauth gem, changes made in create and callback method on 29/04/2010

Check this document. http://blog.brijeshshah.com/integrate-twitter-oauth-in-your-rails-application/comment-page-1/

```
@request_token = UsersController.consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => "callback-url-of-your-twitter-app")
```

Answer (score 3):

When you get a PIN code it means the application is configured as Desktop Application, see http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Authentication. To change this go to the twitter application page: http://twitter.com/apps/, sign in with your twitter account for your application and in `Edit Application Settings`, change the `Application Type` to `Browser`.

Comment: thanks for your reply!
But my app type is set to browser.

any other suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I have no direct solution, but you could try to regenerate a new key, for your twitter app from the twitter side, or even register a new twitter application. But these are brute force solutions;-)