# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) - ArgumentError in TwitterController#login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to integrate Twitter onto my website so that users can register and login using Twitter but here's the error that I get when I go to `http://localhost:3000/twitter/login`

```
ArgumentError in TwitterController#login

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Here's the Twitter controller so far

```
class TwitterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def login
    oauth.set_callback_url("http://#{request.host}/twitter/finalize")

    session[:request_token] = oauth.request_token.token
    session[:request_secret] = oauth.request_token.secret

    redirect_url = oauth.request_token.authorize_url
    redirect_url = "http://" + redirect_url unless redirect_url.match(/^http:\/\//)
    redirect_to redirect_url 
  end

  def finalize
  end

  def oauth
  @oauth ||= Twitter::Client.new(APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_key], APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_secret])
  end
end
```

What's causing it from inside the controller?

Full trace:

```
twitter (4.6.2) lib/twitter/client.rb:51:in `initialize'
app/controllers/twitter_controller.rb:20:in `new'
app/controllers/twitter_controller.rb:20:in `oauth'
app/controllers/twitter_controller.rb:6:in `login'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__1049760818__process_action__595446911__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__770706334__call__235543105__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Any chance you have the stack trace?

Comment: just posted the full trace above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use this API (according to its [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/file/README.md)) is by passing Hash option parameters instead of "real" method arguments:

```
  def oauth
    @oauth ||= Twitter::Client.new(:consumer_key => APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_key], :consumer_secret => APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_secret])
  end
```

Comment: do you know where I need to define "set_callback_url" for twitter integration? I'm getting this error now `undefined method set_callback_url`

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234880/twitter-api-oauth-gem-not-getting-callback

Comment: And if you're still having trouble after trying that solution, I recommend marking this question as accepted and writing a new question clearly stating your new problem, since this one may be resolved